# iOS 17 Standby Mode not working on 2nd Gen SE

Tags: iphone, ios

As per the title, I've upgraded to iOS 17 on my 2nd Gen iPhone and Standby Mode isn't working. If I plug it in (with an official Lightning charger) and put it on its side nothing happens. If I put it on its side *first* and then plug in the charger, I very briefly get a "Welcome to Standby Mode" message that very quickly disappears (less than a second).

I've tried both a soft and hard reset of my phone, and also switched Standby Mode off and on again. I've not tried a wipe-and-restore because it's such a faff I'd like to avoid that if possible. Searching online just gives me dozens of copy-cat articles like "15 top tips on how to get Standby Mode working" which all boil down to taking the steps I've already tried. I can't find anything specific to iPhone SE, but is there a known issue with it? If not, I guess I'll have to try the restore option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it needs an iPhone with an always-on display capability - which is the iPhone 14 Pro or higher.

For models below that, it will only stay on for 30 seconds.
Low power mode must be off.

Sources

- [iOS 17: How to Make StandBy Mode Come On and Stay On](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/make-standby-mode-come-on-and-stay-on/)
- [How to use StandBy Mode on iOS 17 (and which iPhones support it)](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-standby-mode-on-ios-17-and-which-iphones-support-it/)

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. Standby Mode is supported on *all* iOS 17 devices, but Always-on phones give it an, well, always on feature.

Comment: Yes, the mode comes on, but the screen doesn't. No fancy bed-side clock.

Comment: Sorry, only read your first sentence which contradicts the rest of it. If you read my question, it doesn't even come on for one second.

Comment: Then idk, sorry. There's no way I'm going to touch a new OS these days. Wait until about x.3 before I'll go anywhere near it. I remember the days Apple used to get the first release just about workable… long time since that ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Use StandBy to view information at a distance while iPhone is charging](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-standby-iph878d77632/ios):

> To initiate StandBy, connect iPhone to a charger and set it down on its side, keeping it stationary. With the Always On display (on iPhone 14 Pro, iPhone 14 Pro Max, iPhone 15 Pro, and iPhone 15 Pro Max), StandBy stays on to show useful information. **For all other iPhone models, it’s easy to bring up StandBy anytime by tapping the screen, gently nudging the table your iPhone is on, or using Siri.** [bold mine]

Comment: Thanks. I’ve read that. Doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone isn’t working like my friend’s SE. I would make two backups and erase the phone. (One to iCloud and one to a computer - and be sure to encrypt the computer backup if you have health info). I might even delay this if I had a lot of health info and don’t trust a restore until 17.1 is out. (Just in case it’s a bug that took a while for someone to prove to Apple it exists and then fix.)

If you need this to work, after the erase, set up your phone with nothing on it.

- no iCloud, no apps, no restore and test and then seek Apple support if it fails to wake when powered and then jostled when it should be standby mode.
- If standby works, then erase a second time and restore your backup